# SQL Server CPU Usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sp-who2

How to find CPU **usage idle, user, system, IO** for Analyses using SQL Query in SQL Server

Comment: There's not a lot to this question. What have you even tried? Why is Activity Monitor in SSMS not enough?

Comment: using exec sp_who2 am not getting  idle, user, system, IO.

Comment: If status is sleeping it's idle, Hostname or SPID or Login will give you user, program name will give you system, DiskIO gives you IO, CPUTime will give you CPU usage.
What more are you wanting?

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for in SQL Server is this:

```
exec sp_who2
```

**CPU Usage** - CPUTime

**Idle** - Status (*Sleeping*)

**User** - Login / Hostname / SPID (*Depending on what you mean by user*)

**System** - ProgramName

**IO** - DiskIO